# Const keyword in function with an *& argument.

Tags: c++, constants, pass-by-reference

can you please explain why in the following code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    void fun(char * const & x){(*x)++;}
    int main(){ 
        char txt[100]="kolokwium";  
        fun(txt);
        std::cout << txt <<"\n";
    }
```

keyword const is needed for code to compile?

If I remove it I get:

```
 invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘char*&’ from an rvalue of type ‘char*’
```

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`txt` is of type `char[100]`.  It has to be converted to a `char *` in order to be passed to `fun`; this conversion produces an *rvalue*.  You cannot create a non-const reference from an rvalue.

To illustrate, consider what would happen if `fun` were defined as follows:

```
void fun(char *&x) { x++; }
```

What would the following code do (assuming it could compile)?

```
char txt[100]="kolokwium";
fun(txt);                      // Huh?
```

Comment: Allright. So rvalues can only be assigned to const & types, right (or to either const or nonconst && types)? The answer to your question: It would make txt point to next char in table: "
olokwium". But what does that have to do with my question?

Comment: @hungry91: Because that's not possible.  You can't modify an array variable (i.e. you can't do `char txt[100]="..."; txt++;`).

Comment: @hung `txt` is not a pointer, it is an array.  You can convert it to a pointer to the first element implicitly, but that are not the same thing.